# Use android 10 activity zoom transition in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

How to use Android 10 activity zoom transition in Flutter ?

For example :

[image: Zoom transition example]

I've tried to use [fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro) and [page_transition](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition), unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this pr](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/41935), you have to add these lines to your `MaterialApp`'s theme :

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      },
    ),
  ),
  // ...
);
```

Comment: @NithinSai because it was my answer to a question I wrote, and I had to wait some days to accept it, and I forgot ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on GetX use this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GetMaterialApp(
    defaultTransition: Transition.topLevel,
    title: 'YOUR_TITLE',
    home: Home(),
  );
}
```

You just need to add `defaultTransition: Transition.topLevel`